# ActionResult parameters meaning

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[ControllerBase](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs) class has a bunch of methods like `Created` or `CreatedAtAction` which require `value` parameter.

```
[NonAction]
public virtual CreatedAtActionResult CreatedAtAction(string actionName,
            string controllerName,
            object routeValues,
            object value)
{
            return new CreatedAtActionResult(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, value);
}
```

The documentation (really poor one) on it says:

> The value to format in the entity body.

I don't understand what does the parameter stands for? It's not actually used neither within CreatedAtActionResult class itself, nor within the base class. Furthermore, there are no method overloads allow to not use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value is the new object you want to return as response, same one you would pass to `Ok(value)`.

You can pass `null` if you only want to post back the new resource url. Or post it's value, if your java script wants to consume it directly.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetUser(int id) 
{
    var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(id);
    if(user==null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(user);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel user) 
{
    var newUser = new User { /* assign values */ };

    context.Users.Add(newUser);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUser), nameof(UserController), new { id = newUser.Id }, newUser);
}
```

This will return the json response with `newUser` and create a header with url pointing to "http://example.com/user/5" or whatever the id of the newly created user is.

If you don't wish to return a json response, just pass `null`.

Comment: The last line of code `return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUser), nameof(UserController), new { id = newUser.Id, newUser);` looks to be missing a close brace but I'm not sure where.  Probably after `id = newUser.Id` No?

Comment: @RonC: Yea, fixed. Happens when you type code directly into SO and not having IDE open to proof it :P